# Antlr4 python runtime error after generating from grammar

Tags: python, antlr4

I using the following Antlr4 PLSQL grammar files:

https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/sql/plsql.

From here I downloaded as follows:

```
wget https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/sql/plsql/Python3/PlSqlLexerBase.py
wget https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/sql/plsql/Python3/PlSqlParserBase.py

wget https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/sql/plsql/PlSqlLexer.g4
wget https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/sql/plsql/PlSqlParser.g4

mv PlSql*g4 grammars

wget https://www.antlr.org/download/antlr-4.13.1-complete.jar

mv antlr-4.13.1-complete.jar lib
```

Giving me :

```
├── lib
│   ├── antlr-4.13.1-complete.jar
├── grammars1
│   ├── PlSqlLexer.g4
│   └── PlSqlParser.g4
├── PlSqlLexer.g4
├── PlSqlParser.py
```

When I then run:

```
java -jar ./lib/antlr-4.9.3-complete.jar -Dlanguage=Python3 grammars/*g4
```

I get the following generated in `grammars`:

```
grammars-v4-master  PlSqlLexer.interp  PlSqlParserBase.py  PlSqlParserListener.py  __pycache__
master.zip          PlSqlLexer.py      PlSqlParser.g4      PlSqlParser.py          runPLSQL.py
PlSqlLexer.g4       PlSqlLexer.tokens  PlSqlParser.interp  PlSqlParser.tokens
```

I then create the runPLSQL.py Python script :

```
cd grammars
python3 runPLSQL.py ../../plsql/test.sql
```

But this errored with:

```
       
  import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/try2/grammars/runPLSQL.py", line 11, in <module>
    from PlSqlParserListener import PlSqlParserListener
  File "/home/me/try2/grammars/PlSqlParserListener.py", line 6, in <module>
    from PlSqlParser import PlSqlParser
  File "/home/me/try2/grammars/PlSqlParser.py", line 14, in <module>
    from PlSqlParserBase import PlSqlParserBase
  File "/home/me/try2/grammars/PlSqlParserBase.py", line 1, in <module>
    {"payload":{"allShortcutsEnabled":false,"fileTree":{"sql/plsql/Python3":{"items":[{"name":"PlSqlLexerBase.py","path":"sql/plsql/Python3/PlSqlLexerBase.py","contentType":"file"}
NameError: name 'false' is not defined. Did you mean: 'False'?
```

I had to edit the `PlSqlLexerBase.py` file as below to overcome this and similar errors:

1. Replace `:false` with `:False`
2. Replace `:true` with `:True`
3. Replace `:null` with `:None`

But now I get this:

```
  import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/try2/grammars/runPLSQL.py", line 11, in <module>
    from PlSqlParserListener import PlSqlParserListener
  File "/home/me/try2/grammars/PlSqlParserListener.py", line 6, in <module>
    from PlSqlParser import PlSqlParser
  File "/home/me/try2/grammars/PlSqlParser.py", line 14, in <module>
    from PlSqlParserBase import PlSqlParserBase
ImportError: cannot import name 'PlSqlParserBase' from 'PlSqlParserBase' (/home/me/try2/grammars/PlSqlParserBase.py)
```

The `PlSqlParserBase.py` script starts with:

```
{"payload":{"allShortcutsEnabled":False,"fileTree":{"sql/plsql/Python3":{"items":[{"name":"PlSqlLexerBase.py","path":"sql/plsql/Python3/PlSqlLexerBase.py","contentType":"file"},{"name":"PlSqlParserBase.py","path":"sql/plsql/Python3/PlSqlParserBase.py","contentType":"file"}],"totalCount":2},"sql/plsql":{"items":[{"name":"CSharp","path":"sql/plsql/CSharp","contentTy......
```

I notice it references relative pathnames, should all the paths/files exist?

The top of the `runPLSQL.py` script is:

```
import os

import pandas
from antlr4 import InputStream, ParseTreeWalker
from antlr4.CommonTokenStream import CommonTokenStream
from pandas import DataFrame

#from PlSql.grammar.PlSqlListener import PlSqlListener
#from PlSql.grammar.PlSqlLexer import PlSqlLexer
#from PlSql.grammar.PlSqlParser import PlSqlParser
from PlSqlParserListener import PlSqlParserListener
from PlSqlLexer import PlSqlLexer
from PlSqlParser import PlSqlParser


from tabulate import tabulate


class SQLParser(PlSqlListener):
```

I also looked in the autogenerated `master.zip` and it contains file names being referneced, though not the exact same path:

```
unzip -l master.zip | grep PlSql
      896  2024-02-20 11:13   grammars-v4-master/sql/plsql/CSharp/PlSqlLexerBase.cs
      720  2024-02-20 11:13   grammars-v4-master/sql/plsql/CSharp/PlSqlParserBase.cs
      367  2024-02-20 11:13   grammars-v4-master/sql/plsql/Cpp/PlSqlLexerBase.h
      614  2024-02-20 11:13   grammars-v4-master/sql/plsql/Cpp/PlSqlParserBase.h
   109954  2024-02-20 11:13   grammars-v4-master/sql/plsql/Dart/PlSqlLexer.g4
      358  2024-02-20 11:13   grammars-v4-master/sql/plsql/Dart/PlSqlLexerBase.dart
   149085  2024-02-20 11:13   grammars-v4-master/sql/plsql/Dart/PlSqlParser.g4
      571  2024-02-20 11:13   grammars-v4-master/sql/plsql/Dart/PlSqlParserBase.dart
      354  2024-02-20 11:13   grammars-v4-master/sql/plsql/Java/PlSqlLexerBase.java
      610  2024-02-20 11:13   grammars-v4-master/sql/plsql/Java/PlSqlParserBase.java
      259  2024-02-20 11:13   grammars-v4-master/sql/plsql/JavaScript/PlSqlLexerBase.js
      506  2024-02-20 11:13   grammars-v4-master/sql/plsql/JavaScript/PlSqlParserBase.js
   115277  2024-02-20 11:13   grammars-v4-master/sql/plsql/PlSqlLexer.g4
   228726  2024-02-20 11:13   grammars-v4-master/sql/plsql/PlSqlParser.g4
      157  2024-02-20 11:13   grammars-v4-master/sql/plsql/Python3/PlSqlLexerBase.py
      364  2024-02-20 11:13   grammars-v4-master/sql/plsql/Python3/PlSqlParserBase.py
      334  2024-02-20 11:13   grammars-v4-master/sql/plsql/TypeScript/PlSqlLexerBase.ts
      604  2024-02-20 11:13   grammars-v4-master/sql/plsql/TypeScript/PlSqlParserBase.ts
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the files you downloaded for

https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/sql/plsql/Python3/PlSqlLexerBase.py

and

wget https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/sql/plsql/Python3/PlSqlParserBase.py

They should be very small Python scripts, but you seem to have somehow got the github JSON file list. Maybe your `wget` command needs looking at.

Comment: That was exactly it! The downloaded Python files did not contain the Python code, but the github file list as you say.